# php array pagination with mid range numbers

Tags: php, pagination

I have an array pagination class. But that class displays all the page numbers.

I mean if i have 100 pages, it displays all 100 page numbers.

Can someone help me to implement mid range numbers in this pagination class

```
<?php

  class pagination
  {

    /**
     * Properties array
     * @var array   
     * @access private 
     */
    private $_properties = array();

    /**
     * Default configurations
     * @var array  
     * @access public 
     */
    public $_defaults = array(
      'page' => 1,
      'perPage' => 10 
    );

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param array $array   Array of results to be paginated
     * @param int   $curPage The current page interger that should used
     * @param int   $perPage The amount of items that should be show per page
     * @return void    
     * @access public  
     */
    public function __construct($array, $curPage = null, $perPage = null)
    {
      $this->array   = $array;
      $this->curPage = ($curPage == null ? $this->defaults['page']    : $curPage);
      $this->perPage = ($perPage == null ? $this->defaults['perPage'] : $perPage);
    }

    /**
     * Global setter
     * 
     * Utilises the properties array
     * 
     * @param string $name  The name of the property to set
     * @param string $value The value that the property is assigned
     * @return void    
     * @access public  
     */
    public function __set($name, $value) 
    { 
      $this->_properties[$name] = $value;
    } 

    /**
     * Global getter
     * 
     * Takes a param from the properties array if it exists
     * 
     * @param string $name The name of the property to get
     * @return mixed Either the property from the internal
     * properties array or false if isn't set
     * @access public  
     */
    public function __get($name)
    {
      if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_properties)) {
        return $this->_properties[$name];
      }
      return false;
    }

    /**
     * Set the show first and last configuration
     * 
     * This will enable the "<< first" and "last >>" style
     * links
     * 
     * @param boolean $showFirstAndLast True to show, false to hide.
     * @return void    
     * @access public  
     */
    public function setShowFirstAndLast($showFirstAndLast)
    {
        $this->_showFirstAndLast = $showFirstAndLast;
    }

    /**
     * Set the main seperator character
     * 
     * By default this will implode an empty string
     * 
     * @param string $mainSeperator The seperator between the page numbers
     * @return void    
     * @access public  
     */
    public function setMainSeperator($mainSeperator)
    {
      $this->mainSeperator = $mainSeperator;
    }

    /**
     * Get the result portion from the provided array 
     * 
     * @return array Reduced array with correct calculated offset 
     * @access public 
     */
    public function getResults()
    {
      // Assign the page variable
      if (empty($this->curPage) !== false) {
        $this->page = $this->curPage; // using the get method
      } else {
        $this->page = 1; // if we don't have a page number then assume we are on the first page
      }

      // Take the length of the array
      $this->length = count($this->array);

      // Get the number of pages
      $this->pages = ceil($this->length / $this->perPage);

      // Calculate the starting point 
      $this->start = ceil(($this->page - 1) * $this->perPage);

      // return the portion of results
      return array_slice($this->array, $this->start, $this->perPage);
    }

    /**
     * Get the html links for the generated page offset
     * 
     * @param array $params A list of parameters (probably get/post) to
     * pass around with each request
     * @return mixed  Return description (if any) ...
     * @access public 
     */
    public function getLinks($params = array())
    {
      // Initiate the links array
      $plinks = array();
      $links = array();
      $slinks = array();

      // Concatenate the get variables to add to the page numbering string
      $queryUrl = '';
      if (!empty($params) === true) {
        unset($params['page']);
        $queryUrl = '&amp;'.http_build_query($params);
      }

      // If we have more then one pages
      if (($this->pages) > 1) {
        // Assign the 'previous page' link into the array if we are not on the first page
        if ($this->page != 1) {
          if ($this->_showFirstAndLast) {
            $plinks[] = ' <a href="?page=1'.$queryUrl.'">&laquo;&laquo; First </a> ';
          }
          $plinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->page - 1).$queryUrl.'">&laquo; Prev</a> ';
        }

        // Assign all the page numbers & links to the array
        for ($j = 1; $j < ($this->pages + 1); $j++) {
          if ($this->page == $j) {
            $links[] = ' <a class="selected">'.$j.'</a> '; // If we are on the same page as the current item
          } else {
            $links[] = ' <a href="?page='.$j.$queryUrl.'">'.$j.'</a> '; // add the link to the array
          }
        }

        // Assign the 'next page' if we are not on the last page
        if ($this->page < $this->pages) {
          $slinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->page + 1).$queryUrl.'"> Next &raquo; </a> ';
          if ($this->_showFirstAndLast) {
            $slinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->pages).$queryUrl.'"> Last &raquo;&raquo; </a> ';
          }
        }

        // Push the array into a string using any some glue
        return implode(' ', $plinks).implode($this->mainSeperator, $links).implode(' ', $slinks);
      }
      return;
    }
  }
```

### Update:

Here is how i'm using

```
$contacts = array();
if(count($contacts))
    { 
      $pagination = new pagination($contacts,  (isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1), 50);
      $ContactPages = $pagination->getResults();
  if (count($ContactPages) != 0) {
        echo $pageNumbers = $pagination->getLinks();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example how you call it?

Comment: try `for ($j = $this->start + 1; $j < ($this->start + $this->pages + 1); $j++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should declare your class members like `$start`, `$pages` etc. in the class head instead of declaring them on demand. This will improve readability and code quality and helps to avoid errors.

To fix your class, change the for loop and the code around it in `getLinks()` to :

```
// Assign the 'previous page' link into the array if we are not on the first page
if ($this->page != 1) {
  if ($this->_showFirstAndLast) {
    $plinks[] = ' <a href="?page=1'.$queryUrl.'">&laquo;&laquo; First </a> ';
  }
  $plinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->start).$queryUrl.'">&laquo; Prev</a> ';
}

// Assign all the page numbers & links to the array
for ($j = $this->start + 1; $j < ($this->start + $this->pages + 1); $j++) {
   if ($this->page == $j) {
     $links[] = ' <a class="selected">'.$j.'</a> '; // If we are on the same page as the current item
   } else {
     $links[] = ' <a href="?page='.$j.$queryUrl.'">'.$j.'</a> '; // add the link to the array
   }
}

// Assign the 'next page' if we are not on the last page
if ($this->page < $this->pages) {
    $slinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->start + $this->page + 2).$queryUrl.'"> Next &raquo; </a> ';
    if ($this->_showFirstAndLast) {
        $slinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->pages).$queryUrl.'"> Last &raquo;&raquo; </a> ';
    }
}
```

You hadn't $this->start in mind.

I have tested it basically and it worked.

Comment: I have only 77 pages.  After adding your code, I clicked number 12. Now I see ranged from 551 to 627

Comment: Atually, its not working. [Check here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/985f46abd41a83c0a923b26410602773fe17d60a)

Comment: what does the output of the **unchanged** pastebin example look like? can you poste it?

Comment: [Check here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85b68271de5a6aedf0c774722504fcf7f9b0d1a8). You are using current page as 2. So it shows previous page 1 as first, 3 as next, remaining displayed as numbers.